# EXTJS4: How to add values in a template in the view?

Tags: templates, model-view-controller, gridview, extjs4

I have a grid view, and above this gridpanel, I added a template:

```
....items: [{
    xtype: "panel",
    html: new Ext.XTemplate("<div style='margin:5px;'><img src='{imagelink}'/><b>ProductId: {productId}</b></div>")
    },

    {
    xtype: 'grid',
    id:'productGrid',
    height:300,
    columns: [
    {
        header: 'Titel', 
        dataIndex: "title",
        flex:1
    },
    {
        header: 'Typ', 
        dataIndex: "type",
        flex:1
    }
    ]
}]...
```

The data for my grid values are coming from my controller. But how can I add the values dynamicaly to my template, that the placeholer "imagelink" and "productId" can be filled.
Do I have to make something in my model? In my store I get the value back, that fills the grid view, can I also add to this json the placeholders for the template?
THANKS!!

Comment: Do i have to define the template out of the items? ANY HELP PLEASE!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve a reference to the Component containing the XTemplate and call the template's overwrite method, providing a new el and set of data to use to overwrite the template with.

See the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate-method-overwrite

JSFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/prq7Y/

Following MVC, you should be controlling the `XTemplate` from your `Controller`. Business Logic should not reside in the model definition! Observe the Panel's render events (in the Controller) and use those `overwrite` the `XTemplate` accordingly! In my example, I used a button to make it more clear of what needs to happen. The same code could be placed in an event listener residing in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to fill the placeholders, you'll have to call `update()` on the grid (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-update), passing the correct data. If you are wanting to do this when you select a particular record in the grid, you'll want to key on one of the events in the grid's view (like `itemclick`) and `update()` the grid based on the selection's record data.

Comment: Thanks for this hint! The grid is autmatically filled when its called, but the template has no controller. Does it need one? How can I speak to the Compmentent Template?!

Comment: You can use the same controller that you use for the grid, and simply drill up (grid.up(...).down('panel') to the sibling panel. And you don't need to speak to the Template. All you need to do, as I mentioned above, is update() the sibling panel. This will apply whatever data you define in update() to the template. And actually, for this to work, I think you'll have to change html to tpl in your panel config.